# Plot global maximum point and differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have two questions:

(1) I found the global maximum point of the following function

```
FindMaximum[(Exp[-x^2/18]/3 + Exp[-(x - 5)^2/2] + 
    Exp[-(x - 15)^2/8]/2)*(1 + x^2)*Pi/(3 Sqrt[2 Pi]), {x, 15}]
```

but I can't plot the maximum point.

(2) I tried to solve the first-order nonlinear differential equation:

```
DSolve[{x^2 y'[x]+x y[x]==Exp[-x y[x]],y[1]==0},y[x],x]
```

but I can't get the solution. Then, I have to plot the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] := (Exp[-x^2/18]/3 + Exp[-(x - 5)^2/2] + Exp[-(x - 15)^2/8]/2)*(1 + 
    x^2)*Pi/(3 Sqrt[2 Pi])

max = FindMaximum[f[x], {x, 15}]

(* {48.8444, {x -> 15.5135}} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{x, f[x]}], {x, f[x]}] /. max[[2]]}]
```

[image]

```
eqn = {x^2 y'[x] + x y[x] == Exp[-x y[x]], y[1] == 0};

sol = DSolve[eqn, y, x][[1]] // Quiet

(* {y -> Function[{x}, Log[1 + Log[x]]/x]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

{* {True, True} *)

FunctionDomain[y[x] /. sol, x]

(* x > 1/E *)

max2 = NMaximize[{y[x] /. sol, x > 1/E}, x]

(* {0.26438, {x -> 2.14518}} *)

Limit[y[x] /. sol, x -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)

Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0.5, 10},
 PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.3},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{x, y[x]}], {x, y[x]}] /. sol /. max2[[2]]}]
```

[image]